# How to implement Google OpenID authentication in PHP & Test on Localhost

Tags: php, authentication, openid, google-openid

I am new to OpenID, and want to implement Google OpenID authentication on my website. I could not found any examples.

Can anyone suggest me some good tutorials (step by step) or any working example with code to implement Google OpenID authentication using PHP.

Answer (score 30):

I'd suggest using [LightOpenID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid). It's small, easy to use, and has working examples. You probably won't need a tutorial to use it.

Another answer suggests using php-openid, but in my opinion, it's too complicated and has too many dependencies (it is, however, more powerful).

Comment: LightOpenID is now Deprecated and out of date.

Answer (score 4):

use this library http://www.openidenabled.com/php-openid/ 
for the specs and architecture http://wiki.openid.net/ 
a simple tutorial will be http://remysharp.com/2007/12/21/how-to-integrate-openid-as-your-login-system/

Comment: 1) There are problems with the JanRain url (openidenabled) that have been used as a source for OpenID scripts. The folders no longer contain code, so I don't know if the project has become a pay-for commercial enterprise, but the downloadable packages at JanRain are no longer there.

2) That tutorial at remysharp does more damage than instruction, I feel. Go ahead and copy the code, and try it for yourself. I'm not allowed enough characters here to explain the places that tutorial will fail the reader. I would really like to find a good beginner tutorial to make OpenID work with PHP.