# how to allow users to login to my web application using their google account?

Tags: php, google-authentication

I am developing a web application in which I want to allow users to use my application using their google account without having to register with my application separately just like we can do on stackoverflow. Please point me to some kind of tutorial or detailed documentation about how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion, you would cover a way bigger user base with OpenID, Google Accs are a subset of accs that can be used for it.

Comment: possibly the same question..?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971914/how-to-implement-google-openid-authentication-in-php-test-on-localhost

Comment: Thanks everyone else for answering my question, +1'd everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe look [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/accounts/)

Comment: The link is broken. (This is the reason you should paste the relevant information from the page instead of just giving a link.)

Comment: Information on this kind of topic imho outdates faster than the webpage. if you are interested in the old info waybackmachine helps. it is simple. http://web.archive.org/web/20120225144934/http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/accounts

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate OpenID, which enables users to login to applications around the web without the need to create a new account. See this page, "Single Sign On with OpenID"
: http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_php.html

Here is another tutorial link:
[Single Sign-On with OpenID and Google Part 1](http://www.merchantos.com/blog/makebeta/php/single-sign-on-with-openid-and-google-part-1)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This [solution](http://andrewpeace.com/php-google-login-class.html) might help you